# TypeScript fails to convert `any` type to the strongly defined type

Tags: typescript

I have a data model in one of my projects which resembles (but it is not identical to) the data returned by an API. When I call that API (using any client, let's say axios), TypeScript fails to correctly assign the returned data to the corresponding type. To make it clear, let's look at this code:

```
type MyType = {
    name: string,
    isValid: boolean
}

const myType : MyType = JSON.parse(`
    {
        "name": "test"
    }
`)

console.log(myType.isValid)
```

The mechanism of calling an API and assigning the response to a type is exactly as I described in the code. However, if we run this code we will see that `isValid` is not defined on the object. This is while `isValid` has a `boolean` type which should fall back to the default value of `false`. Does it mean that `TypeScript` does NOT have any casting mechanism and it simply acts as a `linter` in this case?

Comment: TypeScript does literally nothing at runtime, not in this case nor in any other case. It's purely a compile-time construct.

Comment: I wish Typescript would work the way you describe, but it unfortunately doesn't. You have to have your own parser that would validate the data and map it to correct type. This is why libraries like "runtypes" exists, but it still would not help you when you are dealing with data coming from an external api so you need to parse it yourself

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: That's right, but when being compiled back to JS, it should really do something about the cast! (I think)

Comment: At "compile time", Typescript won't type-check the JSON string in your code since it's just a string (and if it comes from an API, there is no way for typescript to check it anyway). So if you cast it directly into a type without checking if all the properties you want are there, you get this situation.

Comment: @Kokodoko: I meant, it can turn it into a method, and it can do some validation. But I know such discussion isn't fit for SO.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder So you're saying that for whatever type, interface or whatever you define, TypeScript should conjure up some conversion code that would convert any type of input to your defined type? You could create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) for that, but I don't think that reception will be positive.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Yes, it is something opinion based, I also know that it would reduce the performance at runtime. But the behavior of typescript confused me as I am used to the casting mechanics in strongly typed compiled languages.

Comment: What strongly typed language provides more casting capabilities than this? Sure, there's automatic up/down-casting of primitives in most, but what language will automatically convert a raw map/object/struct to a property typed object?

Comment: you can use something like yup or zop to validate your input. https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup / https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod